# Convention for mongo's limit and skip method in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm new to JS and trying to build an REST API. 
I have a database which documents and I implemented a search method to search in every field using indexes. Now I want to enable some kind of pagination so I used limit() and skip(). 
My question is: by convention, should a pages start a 1 or 0? By that I mean if i do:

```
let userArray = await User.find({$text: {$search:keyword}})
            .select(["-password", "-__v"])
            .limit(perPage)
            .skip(perPage*page)
```

if I want 3 items per page and the second page, should the url be:

```
url?limit=3&page=1
```

or

```
url?limit=3&page=2
```

Sorry if question is already asked and dumb but I try to write code as clean as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally the pages start at 1. It won't make much difference having page 0 as the starting page but other option is much more conventional and clean as you want.

Also to skip and limit, you can do something like below -

skip = perpage * (page - 1)

limit = perpage

For example perpage is 3,

Page 1 :

skip = 3 * (1-1) = 0, skip 0 items for page 1

Page 2 :

skip = 3 * (2-1) = 3, skip 3 items fro page 2 and so on